# Does SQL Server CLR Integration support configuration files?

Tags: c#, sql-server, configuration-files, sqlclr, configurationmanager

I use SQL Server CLR Integration to create an ASSEMBLY.

Load Command:
`CREATE ASSEMBLY TcpClr FROM 'G:\TcpClrTest.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE`

Without App.Config

The dll code contains :
`string ip=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connection"].ToString();`

Also the App.config contains :

`<appSettings>
    <add key="connection" value="127.0.0.1"/>
 </appSettings>`

But when I execute the PROCEDURE,the SQL Server shows an error `System.NullReferenceException`

Does SQL Server CLR Integration support App.config files?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to place a **sqlservr.exe.config** file in the **\Binn** folder of that instance's root folder. For example:

**C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn**

If you are using SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) or newer, you should be able to find the exact location via the following query, which shows the full path to **sqlservr.exe**:

```sql
SELECT [filename] FROM sys.dm_server_services WHERE servicename LIKE N'SQL Server (%';
```

In your code, you need this line at the top:

```cs
using System.Configuration;
```

And then this will work:

```cs
[SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None, IsDeterministic = true)]
public static SqlString GetConfig(SqlString WhichOne)
{
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
    return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[WhichOne.Value].ToString();
}
```

Contents of the **sqlservr.exe.config** file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="Stuff" connectionString="Trusted_Connection=true; Enlist=false;" />
      <add name="ClrTest" connectionString="boo hoo" />
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

It is important to note that, as stated in the "Using an Application Configuration..." link, changes made to the config file are not immediately available. **HOWEVER**, you do *not* need to force a reload by doing one of the methods mentioned in that article (i.e. `DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE`, and restarting SQL Server). All that is required to get current information is to reload the particular section you are using via [ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(string sectionName)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection.aspx) as shown in the example above. *Please see note below regarding usage and performance.*

Resources:

- [Using System.Configuration.dll in .NET sprocs and UDFs](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/using-system-configuration-dll-in-net-sprocs-and-udfs/)
- [Using an Application Configuration (app.config/web.config) File in SQL Server CLR Integration](http://www.sqlclr.net/Articles/tabid/54/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/33/Default.aspx)

---

Also, unless you absolutely need to, you shouldn't create your assembly as `UNSAFE`. If you are just trying to make TCP connections to other machines, that should only require `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`.

---

**USAGE AND PERFORMANCE**

As suggested by Joe B in a [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183917/does-sql-server-clr-integration-support-configuration-files#comment70730750_28184879), there is a slight performance hit for the `RefreshSection` operation. If the code containing the refresh is going to be called more than once every couple of minutes, then it can have a noticeable impact (an impact that is unnecessary given the lack of frequency of a config file changing). In this case, you will want to remove the call to `RefreshSection` from the code that is called frequently and handle the refresh independently.

One approach would be to have a SQLCLR Stored Procedure or Scalar Function that just does the refresh and nothing else. This can be executed whenever a change it made to the config file.

Another approach would be to unload the App Domain which will reload the config file upon the next time any SQLCLR object in that database is referenced. One fairly simple method to reload all App Domains in a particular Database (but not across the entire Instance) is to flip the `TRUSTWORTHY` setting On and then Off again, or Off and then On again, depending on the current state of that setting. The code below will check the current state of that setting and flip it accordingly:

```sql
IF (EXISTS(
    SELECT  sd.*
    FROM    sys.databases sd
    WHERE   sd.[name] = DB_NAME() -- or N'name'
    AND     sd.[is_trustworthy_on] = 0
   ))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Enabling then disabling TRUSTWORTHY...';
    ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
    ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF;
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Disabling then enabling TRUSTWORTHY...';
    ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF;
    ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
END;
```

*Please* do not use any of the more drastic methods -- `DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE`, disabling then enabling the `clr enabled` system setting, restarting the Instance, etc -- as it is almost never necessary to do so. Especially restarting the Instance, or `DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE` which drops *all* cached data for the entire Instance, which affects much more than just SQLCLR.

### UPDATE REGARDING SQL SERVER ON LINUX

SQL Server is now, starting with version 2017, available on Linux (woo hoo!). However, it seems that reading from the app config file does *not* work on Linux. I have tried many combinations of `sqlservr.exe.[Cc]onfig` and  `sqlservr.[Cc]onfig`, etc, and the like and have not gotten anything to work. Specifying a config file can't work as that requires `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` permission and only `SAFE` Assemblies are allowed on Linux (as of right now, at least). If I find a way to get it working I will post the details here.

Comment: Yes,I just want to make TCP connections to other machines.The config file's name  must be **sqlservr.exe.config** ? `<appSettings>` must be changed to `<connectionStrings>`,right ?

Comment: @zhengkang Yes, that is the name of the file as it will match the `sqlservr.exe` executable in that same folder. I believe you _can_ have an `appSettings` section, but I was getting an error when trying to pull the value of a particular key. On the other hand, I was successful at getting the `connectionStrings` section to read without a problem. You can try both, but I could only prove (at this point) that one of them definitely worked.

Comment: Thanks,I have done as you said,it successful.  You suggest me change `UNSAFE` to `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`,but the dll code have a `static` var to sotre a value get from DB, `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` can not be allowed,so i choose `UNSAFE`

Comment: @zhengkang Glad this worked. Regarding `UNSAFE`, check out what I recommended here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179038/can-i-store-information-in-a-static-variable-in-a-sql-server-clr-assembly-withou/28179162#28179162 Maybe that will work for you. It is worth trying.

Comment: @zhengkang Please see the update I just posted related to refreshing the config file to get the changes. The methods of reloading that I had mentioned are all unnecessary as I found a very simple and appropriate method.

Comment: Thank you very much.Now,I have another problem about TCP connections.Could you give me any suggestions?   [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230475/socket-communication-in-clr-integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230475/socket-communication-in-clr-integration)

Comment: Doesn't calling ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings") every time cause a small performance hit since the section is re-read from disk? This approach seems unnecessary because the config file rarely changes. I would prefer to run DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE when changes are deployed (normally during non-peak hours).

Comment: @JoeB Fair enough. I did test and performance was definitely worse across 10k rows calling the Refresh each time. I have updated to clarify for readers how to approach this. Still, `DBCC FREEYSTEMCACHE` is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

You'll obviously be getting a `NullReferenceException` because `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connection"]` is returning null and then you are calling ToString() on a null.

Until you posted your question the top ranking page for a Google search on `CLR Integration app.config` was this 
[Using an Application Configuration (app.config/web.config) File in SQL Server CLR Integration](http://www.sqlclr.net/Articles/tabid/54/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/33/Default.aspx).

In the associated article by [Jonathan Kehayias](http://www.sqlclr.net/Articles/tabid/54/articleType/AuthorView/AuthorID/3/Default.aspx), he states

> A common part of programming in .NET is to use an configuration file
>   to store configuration information in an easily modifiable location. 
>   The app.config or web.config file is an invaluable inclusion in most
>   .NET projects and developers may need to maintain this functionality
>   as a part of logic sharing between objects in the database and the
>   application as well.  **The problem is that SQL CLR doesn't allow use of
>   the System.Configuration class in SQLCLR projects**.

He then goes on to detail a workaround which involves editing the project file to inject a new key into an ItemGroup that links your app.config to the project. From there you can do some basica wrangling from within your code to create a UserDefinedFunction to return the connection string or appSetting you require.

You are best to read the article posted by him at the aforementioned Url as it's not my area and I would just end up blatantly plagiarizing his content to provide a step by step of how to do.

Comment: You can use `System.Configuration` all you want; explicitly obtain one via `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration()`.  The static `ConfigurationManager` methods obviously do not work, but the **bold portion** of the statement is inaccurate.  The only trick is determining the location of the app.config, and this is where SQL CLR plays "tricks" because the `AppDomain` obscures all location information from e.g. `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`.  However, if you can use a fixed path to locate your app.config, then you are home free!  Only other detail is not using CM's static methods.

Comment: You didn't include the code and now the link is down. This is what will always happen eventually with link answers.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to access the same SQL Server that the CLR is running on? If so, you can use a special type of connection string called a "context connection".

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131053.aspx

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true")) 
{
    connection.Open();
    // Use the connection
}
```

Basically you tell the code that it should use the underlying SQL Server (in that context) and you won't even need to specify connection info. If you're trying to run arbitrary reusable code as a CLR, you're probably committing some sort of software crime and should just not do that.

Comment: RIght on!  How ironic that all of the examples seen are concerned with connection strings....

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.  It's working perfectly for me, and I can install my assembly on any instance now and it will work perfectly.

```
   SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder("");
        sqlb.ContextConnection = true;
        string newConnStr = sqlb.ToString();

        using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(newConnStr))

        {
            c.Open();

            //This is the database name
            DatabaseName = c.Database;

            //We need to use some simple SQL to get the server and instance name.
            //Returned in the format of SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT @@SERVERNAME [Server]", c);
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr.Read())
            {
                ServerName = rdr["Server"].ToString();
            }
        }
```