# Socket Communication in CLR Integration

Tags: c#, sql-server, sockets, sqlclr

Does socket communication do well in CLR Integration.

For example: I have a PROC created in CLR Integration.It get all data from a table,and just want to send the data to TCP Server.

Command:

```sql
CREATE ASSEMBLY TcpClr FROM 'G:\TcpClrTest.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SendDataToSrv
(
@NAME nvarchar(20)
)
AS EXTERNAL NAME 
TcpClr.[TcpClrTest.TcpSend].SqlProce;
GO

EXEC SendDataToSrv 'cdc.dbo_Test_CT'
```

Some code in **TcpClrTest.dll**:

```cs
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tableName", con))
{
     using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
     {
         while (reader.Read())
          {
              //string value = reader[0].ToString();
              //tcpClient.Write(value);
              //  ......get all data and send to tcp server.
          }
      }
}
```

I have exec the proc with command `EXEC SendDataToSrv 'cdc.dbo_Test_CT'`, the table has 100000 rows and 18 columns.It would cost about 5 minutes.Also I copy the same code to common function ,not CLR Integration,It only cost about 30 seconds.TCP Server and SQL Server running on same machine.If I delete `tcpClient.Write(value)` code,just get data from table,it does quickly.

In CLR Integration,anything I should do to improve

Comment: Why do you need to send data from inside of SQL Server? It's supported but in 99% of the cases this is architecturally a bad idea. It is brittle. Just make the app send the data.

Comment: When a Server start,it will get all data from SQL Server and store them to memory.When some of table's data changed,such as `update`,`delete`,`insert`.,I must get the change message and reload the changed data to memory.So I choose CDC to get DML message and CLR Integration to view the CDC table and send data to Server.Are there any more better method?

Comment: What service are you sending the data to? Why can't that service read from the CDC tables, just like it reads the data when the server starts? If any TCP communication is needed, it would only be to tell the remote service to check for updates.

Comment: @zhengkang That is quite frankly stupid. Use [Query Notification Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. Use .net as an app server.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do [Cache invalidation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Comment: @Aron Query Notification only can tell me the DML operation 
immediately, it donot tell me which row was changed.

Comment: @zhengkang https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx That wasn't part of your OP question. There was in your question `SELECT * FROM tableName`.

Comment: However delta merging is not simple. Also...frankly if the data is too large to re-query each time, its too large to put in your cache. Also, consider just putting the tables in question in memory in SQL server if you really do have perf issues. Also I seriously doubt that what you are doing will actually improve perf.

Comment: @srutzky TCP Server,also the Server will store the data to memory.SQL Server send data to TCP Server is really not good idea?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Why do you want to store this info in memory. What will it be used for and how? How are you merging the updates and deletes into the current data in memory?

Comment: @srutzky Because I have a Data Center Server, it will store data in memory, so other app which want to get data from SQL Server can get from DC,DC like a `Memory Database`.

Comment: How much data are we talking about? How many tables? How many rows each? How often will those tables be read? Are we talking about millions of reads? Are you sure SQL Server can't handle the load as is? I am wondering if this is premature optimization.

Comment: @srutzky more to the point. Are you sure you can do better than the Microsoft SQL Server team at building an in memory database. This is almost definitely premature optimization (de-optimization as the case appears in fact) since its clear you don't even know how SQL Server in memory pages work. You need to know how the entire system works (back to front, inside out) before you can optimize it.