# what is the alternative of SQL CLR calls?

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2016, sqlclr

I'm using SQL server 2016 for my .Net application[Framework 4.5]. I'm using CLR calls in SQL to pass some data to client-side/browser based on CRUD operations.

Eg: SignalR Notifications/calls, web-service calls using assemblies

Do we have any alternative w.r.to., SQL server CLR to make direct web-service calls. Any suggestions/help would be appreciated

Comment: How about a background worker that does this, based off of data from the database?

Comment: Might help if you could explain what features you're seeking/seeking to avoid such that you need an alternative. What's the problem with SQL CLR?

Comment: SQLCLR was never an option for making Web service calls. That's the job of client applications and services like SSIS

Comment: If you want to perform CRUD just use ADO.NET. If you want to orchestrate web services, build an orchestration web service. Or have the services talk to each other. If you want to have one service call another add a Service Reference to each other. You'll have to explain what you actually try to do.

Comment: OP has an XY problem.....

Comment: @MitchWheat more like "I inherited this horrible legacy application and don't know what to do with it". One has to find what that legacy application did in order to find a fix first. SQLCLR is only a symptom

Answer (score 0):

If you can base the calls on things happening in the database, @lasse's suggestion above to have a service retrieving data and do the necessary calls are a good idea.

Other than that SQLCLR is probably your best bet. I know that SQL Server Service Broker has the notion of external calls, but when I looked into it a few years ago, the performance was not there.

A third option could be to use SQL Server Machine Learning Services and its Python capabilities to call out of the database and let your calls execute outside. This would, however, require SQL 2017. In 2016 you could use R but I do not know if R has the capabilities to do what you want to do.

Hope this helps!

Niels

Comment: No SQLCLR was **never** meant for web service calls. It's a pretty awful idea, one authors and speaker warned against since SQLCLR was introduced back in 2005. That's because SQLCLR delays transactions and consumes the same memory the database would use for buffering. ML services is completely inappropriate as well. It's about *machine learning*, not for scripting. You don't need ML services to just run a Python script *outside* the server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - since `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` explicitly gave DNS and web service permissions for outbound calls, I think it's a stretch to think that such calls were not anticipated.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever and actively *discouraged* since 2005, for the reasons I gave. Even back then Teched speakers would talk about their "No, don't do that!" experiences. Besides, what looked nice in 2005 was recognized as a rather bad idea only a couple of years earlier. Some stuff was included for marketing reasons, not for any real technical benefit. 2005 was before WS-*, when people thought web services were the answer to life, the universe and everything.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, it is easy to say "SQLCLR was never meant for web service calls. It's a pretty awful idea". I would be interested in knowing how you would solve the problem, if you need to do some calls to web-services, etc. based on events happening in the database - and you do not have access to the application which causes these events to happen in the database. I'd also be interested in how many SQLCLR solutions you have implemented, and what they did.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm with Niels on this one (no surprise there ;-). Your continued objection anytime anyone mentions this topic is, _at best_, obsolete. It doesn't matter what anyone said back in 2005. Huge improvements were made in 2012 re: performance (revamped memory (including where SQLCLR operates) and constant folding UDFs; 64 bit also made a big difference). And, most folks didn't (and many still don't) understand how to properly use SQLCLR / best practices. Saying SQLCLR "consumes memory and delays transactions" is disingenuous because all operations do those things. Yes, (cont.)

Comment: SQLCLR _can_ be bad, but so can horribly written T-SQL (RBAR, Scalar UDFs, etc). Do WebService calls lock up threads? Not so much if you call a service on the same network, and not if done properly. Besides, SQL Server can still force threads to sleep (look at clr quantum punishment). And it doesn't matter _who_ said anything negative. One well respected person said that app domains can't be unloaded without a restart, yet I know of 4 ways. Another said that config files can't be reloaded without a restart yet it's easy to do. I discuss both in this answer (also on S.O.): (cont.)

Comment: [Does SQLCLR support config files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28184879/577765). If you don't like this approach, then fine. But please stop spreading this misinformation. It would be far more helpful (and accurate) to warn folks of the _potential_ pitfalls (e.g. internet connections are riskier than intranet, properly close external resources, etc). Yes, in some cases SQLCLR, especially for Web Services, is unnecessary / ill-advised. But, intended or not, there are enough folks doing this successfully to warrant you updating your info on this. [Thanks](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=so_52380775).

Answer (score 0):

One of our client had a similar infrastructure, to communicate between 2 different systems.

#### First approach using SQLCLR inside a table trigger

Trigger on a table calls SQLCLR procedure which makes a HTTP web API request to post data.

***Issues found*** : As it is a complete transaction scope, the CRUD operations triggered by front end started to wait till a message has been published by SQLCLR.

#### Second approach was making SQLCLR procedure to implement Asynchronous HTTP request

Making SQLCLR procedure as Asynchronous method using threading namespace.

***Issues found*** : Even this method were causing issues, and was losing messages when the endpoint was not available.

#### Third approach using SQL SERVICE BROKER as an wrapper around SQLCLR

Implemented SQL server broker to break the transactions between trigger and publishing messages. And make HTTP request from SQL service broker target activation stored procedure. This solved the issue as it breaks the transaction after adding to the queue.

***Advantage*** using service broker as an wrapper around SQLCLR is you can break the transaction and messages are stored in queue and never lost and also we can use service broker
to communicate between 2 different SQL server instance if needed.